# Import a static method in dart

Tags: dart

Assume I have a class containing a static function:

```dart
class TextUtils {
   static Text bold(String text) {
     return Text(text, TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),);
   }
}
```

So when I want to use it:

```
import 'ui/text.dart'

// ...
TextUtils.bold("Hello");
```

**Is there any way not to bring class name before function?** Like it is in Kotlin?

```dart
import 'ui/text.dart' // someHow
// ...
bold("Hello");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such feature in Dart.

Actually [there is the opposite](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#specifying-a-library-prefix) of it. A global function can be used with a prefix, as if it is a static method of some class.

```
import 'package:lib2/lib2.dart' as lib2;

lib2.Element element2 = lib2.Element();
```

Comment: I'd also take this as a recommendation to simply make your function a top level function. The Dart style guide explicitly discourages creating classes with only static members - you should just make a library with top-level members instead, and only import that with a prefix if you want or need to avoid naming conflicts.